# Google cloud platform data fusion instance triggering

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I want to trigger the google data fusion instance with the command as follows

```
POST -H "Authorization: Bearer ${AUTH_TOKEN}" "${CDAP_ENDPOINT}/v3/namespaces/namespace-id/apps/pipeline-name/workflows/DataPipelineWorkflow/start"
```

but I cant able to figure out one thing that what will be the `CDAP_ENDPOINT` in this kindly help me out by telling that from where i can find out the `cdap_endpoint`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is nicely explained in GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/reference/cdap-reference#set-up), as you might be able to get Data fusion API endpoint throughout the following command lines, invoking them in cloud shell:

```
export INSTANCE_ID=your-Data fusion instance-id
export CDAP_ENDPOINT=$(gcloud beta data-fusion instances describe \
--location=us-central1 \
--format="value(apiEndpoint)" \
${INSTANCE_ID})
```